# React Redux - on submit wont fire action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action

I am trying to fire the Redux action on form submit in React but it does nothing and it does not show any errors at all.

action:

```
export const addLead = (lead) => (dispatch) => {
const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/leads/'
axios.post(url, lead)
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_LEAD,
            payload: res.data
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

};

reducer :

```
      case "ADD_LEAD":
      return {
          ...state,
          leads: [...state, action.payload]
      }
```

And here is my Form component:

```
const Form = () => {

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message:''
})

const {name, email, message} = formData;

const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}

const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit")
    const {name, email, message} = formData;
    const lead = {name, email, message}
    console.log('Leads: ',lead)
    addLead(lead)
}

return(
   <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      .... Form .... 
   </form>

export default connect(null, {addLead})(Form);
```

If I submit the form in the Redux dev tools I dont see the action nor any error in the console. I can see the correct data in the states in the console.log and also the 'submit' so the function onSubmit is fired. Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: You need to make sure you're using `addLead` from props! That would look something like this: `const Form = ({addLead}) => { ... }`

Comment: Thank you! I added this and now it sends data to the server, but in Redux extension I do not see the action.

Comment: Is your axios post successful? It looks like you're only dispatching the action in the `then` callback, meaning for it to be dispatched your request will need to be successful. If it _is_ successful, then look into your redux extension config (are other actions showing up?)

Comment: The post request is successful. On page refresh the new data are shown. Other actions are getLeads and deleteLead and these are displayed in the extension. (Get Lead on page load, delete onclick)

Comment: @Nick The action is no displayed because I receive an error TypeError: state is not iterable. I have take a look on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `addLead` from *props*, meaning you need to make sure you're grabbing it from the `props` argument of your `Form` component:

```
const Form = ({addLead}) => {
  // Component code stays the same
}
```

It's important to remember that `connect` will map state *to props* and map dispatch *to props*.

Answer (score 0):

@Nick is right, we didn't see the full component code to judge where `addLead` comes from.

1- addLead need to be use consumed from component props(which is wired down using react-redux `connect` higher order function)

2- for `async actions` I see you are using a thunk but you maybe forgot to `return` when you call `axios` inside the thunk.

```js
export const addLead = (lead) => (dispatch) => {

    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/leads/';

    return axios.post(url, lead)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ADD_LEAD,
                payload: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think he needs to return anything from `addLead` right? as long as OP's calling the `dispatch` function with some data it should indeed be dispatched.